# Why is there a "session_set_save_handler" warning whenever Civi cron runs?

Tags: drupal, cron

I am using CiviCRM 5.23.4 with Drupal 7.69, though this issue is not new to this version of Civi.

Every time Civi cron runs, I get a warning in the Drupal Recent log messages:

Warning: session_set_save_handler(): Cannot change save handler when session is active in drupal_session_initialize() (line 242 of /home/XXXX/www/www/includes/session.inc).

Any suggestions for how to address this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What version of php? Not the one listed at /admin/reports/status but the one that cron actually uses. If you aren't sure put `watchdog('test', phpversion());` in line 241 in includes/session.inc and then check what it puts in the drupal log.

Comment: Good question. 7.2.28

Comment: That should be ok, and in fact you maybe started seeing the messages whenever you started with php 7.2. Anything session-related in civicrm.settings.php? Or an extension? Although it seems like that line would run earlier before civi starts. I guess you don't see the message when it's just regular drupal cron running?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this Demerit. It only happens when Civi cron runs, not when drupal cron runs. I wouldn't know what to look for in terms of "anything session-related". And I'm also not sure what you mean about extensions. Sorry, I'm an amateur with this stuff :-)

Comment: For extensions I mean in civicrm under Administer - System Settings - Manage Extensions. But my guess right now is that it's not actually drupal 7.69 and is maybe only partially upgraded and maybe still has files from 7.67? Or a non-standard drupal module is causing it, on the drupal side under admin - modules. Except then you would probably see it for drupal cron, but maybe civi causes an extra call or something. I'm not really sure here.

Comment: Oh yes, I am using a number of Civi extensions and many Drupal modules. I keep everything up to date carefully so there shouldn't be any 7.67 files lying around. So should I disable extensions and test?

Comment: Disabling and testing is one way. If any are about login or session management they would be obvious ones to check first.

Comment: None of the Civi extensions are concerned with session management as far as I can tell, but maybe some Drupal modules. I'll do a bit of testing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tested by disabling all Civi extensions and running cron, but the same issue occurs. And since it does not happen when Drupal cron runs, I did not try disabling the many Drupal extensions. None is concerned with session handling as far as I can tell. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Getting this same error (Drupal 7.87, CiviCRM 5.46.0) Sure would like to find the answer

Comment: I continue to have this issue with Civi 5.46.2, PHP 7.4 and Drupal 7.87, so I'm afraid I can't offer any new insights.